# Flurry Analytics vs Google Analytics on the mobile platform

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, analytics

I am working on a mobile app on the Android platform (and going forward for the iPhone) and am evaluating the [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html) and [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/overview.html) platforms for the app. Both platforms have SDKs for the Android and the iPhone and seem very similar in most ways.

Do any of you have experience with both or either and could you highlight some of the noticeable differences between the two?

thanks!

Comment: If only the answers had answered the question.  It's the answers that are not constructive...

Comment: @Carl I agree. I have edited it to be more specific rather than ask for recommendations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have used Flurry which was really really easy to setup but kinda scary in all the information that it sends to the Flurry servers. You might want to check out this [article](http://gizmodo.com/5570942/one-in-five-android-apps-access-your-private-data) about android apps and private data. At the very least you may want to give your users an option to opt out of sending the analytical data.

I actually ended up removing it from my apps, just because I didn't really use any of the data for anything, and it added extra threads running and extra KBs to the apk.

Comment: Thanks BrennaSoft (and apologize for taking a few months to respond). The client ended up selecting Flurry even after my disclosures.

Comment: Yeah, flurry is good enough! More better than GA

Answer (score 12):

[Here's a list](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/articles/marketing/7-solutions-for-tracking-mobile-analytics/) of some more mobile tracking services / products:

- [Admob Analytics](http://analytics.admob.com/home/)
- [AppClix](http://www.appclix.com/)
- [Bango](http://bango.com/mobileanalytics/)
- [Medialets](http://www.medialets.com/)

Haven't used any of those, currently just digging through demos, API and SDK samples. Comments from people who have used them would be most welcome!

Answer (score 9):

Localytics is another free option in this space.  Unlike the other guys the client library is open source and the service is real time instead of aggregating every few hours.  There has never been any problems with the data they collect but if you have concerns you can just comment out any of the relevant lines in the source.

Check them out: http://www.localytics.com

Comment: It is free for 30 days only.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer **Flurry**.

For me **google** Analytics is optimized for web site and not for mobile app. In google i can't find data on unique user but most data reffering on user visits.

With Flurry you can track your app version, and the relative crash for each version.

Answer (score 2):

BuzzBox SDK also has a real-time analytics module. I use it in a few Apps where I also use the BuzzBox scheduler.
More info here:  http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/analytics

Comment: Can anyone gives suggestion which one is the best Google Analytics or flurry Analytics. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AskingPoint App analytics is another new mostly free option with some interesting features that no one else has. For example the ability to use your analytics to show the APIs embedded Rating Widget or Polling Widget.

Check it out at: www.askingpoint.com