# Google Analytics Android SDK

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics Android SDK:

```
mTracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
mTracker.start(getString(R.string.googleCode), this);
mTracker.trackPageView("/MainActivity");
mTracker.dispatch();
```

However I haven't received any data when I view my report.  I have checked my code to ensure it is correct. I have also waited 3 days and still nothing.  The status remains as "Tracking not installed". I should add that mTracker.dispatch)_ returns true. I can't find the API documentation, but I assume this means something good happened rather than something bad.

Does any one know why this would happen? Perhaps Google Analytics Android SDK only sends data over WiFi and not 3G?

SOLUTION

I noticed logcat printing a message under the tag "googleanalytics". The message was:

```
WARN/googleanalytics(2518): Dispatcher thinks it finished, but there were 1 failed events
```

This was caused by a space in my label parameter:

```
mTracker.trackEvent("Clicks", // Category
                "Login", // Action
                "Main Activity", // Label
                -1); // Value
```

It should have been:

```
mTracker.trackEvent("Clicks", // Category
                "Login", // Action
                "MainActivity", // Label
                -1); // Value
```

I then had to uninstall the application because once this problem occurred it seems googleanalytics won't work.  The database it uses must be deleted...at least it seems that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if you have Analytics setup properly and are doing everything ok, take a look at [this page](http://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting)
If none of the points listed at that page apply to you, it just might be Google Analytics malfunctioning.

I had similar problems with GA myself a while back. Sometimes GA is just slow and it takes one or two days for results to appear, but one day I noticed that nothing got registered eventhough I had been busy testing my app and dispatching of GA events seemed to work fine. When I tried it again the next week, somehow everything seemed to work again, but the results from that particular day never turned up. I guess GA isn't the most "stable" service Google is providing.

If you're interested in alternative solutions, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144100/flurry-analytics-vs-google-analytics-on-the-mobile-platform)

Comment: That link is not valid anymore unfortunately.

Comment: @IgorG. I noticed a lot of links to GA help pages don't work anymore. I've fixed the broken link, but if it breaks again try googling for "google analytics troubleshooting"

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to call mTracker.setDebug(true) to get more useful debugging info.