# How to do mobile analytics using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, google-analytics, analytics

I am looking for a good solution to do mobile analytics for Jquery  mobile . I did check this question

[Flurry Analytics vs Google Analytics on the mobile platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144100/flurry-analytics-vs-google-analytics-on-the-mobile-platform)

but these are all solutions for a platform specific/ phone manufacturer specific but jquery mobile works on all platforms irrespective of the manufacturer or operating system. Essentially i am looking for a analytics solution for webapps.

Additional Info:-
bango seems expensive at $49/month. Admob wont work since we dont need it for advertising and not for placing ads.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following:

```js
<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-xx']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    try {

        hash = location.hash;

        if (hash && hash.length > 1) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', hash.substr(1)]);
        } else {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        }
    } catch(err) {

    }

});
</script>
```

The 'pageshow' event fires even for the first page, so don't think you want to include the _trackPageview with the GA setup.  Also, location.hash will return url with the "#" character so hash.subtr(1) cleans that off which will normalize hash/pushstate visitors.

Update 11/30/11: Added check for hash length for ie bug (from: Paulo Manuel Santos).

Comment: I found that in some cases with IE and after clicking the back button the url is rendered with an empty hash (http:blabla/Index#).
So I changed it to `if (hash && hash.length > 1)`.

Comment: For the `else` I used `location.pathname`.

Comment: Anyone tried this solution and found it *didn't* work? This setup works only for the app that I put out as an online demo site, but not for any installations of my app on mobile phones.

Comment: @user316727, check out this for using google analytics in native apps,  normal code isn't going to work: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/12/google-analytics-enhancements-for.html

Answer (score 1):

I use the following bits of code for Google Analytics and it works well:

The following is pretty much the normal Google Analytics setup:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '**-*****-**']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

The update for jQuery Mobile is here so that each pseudo-page is logged:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role=page]', 'pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    var url = location.href;
    try  {
        if (location.hash) {
            url = location.hash;
        }
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);
    } 
    catch(error) {
        // error catch
    }
});
```

Comment: Will try this out and send my feedback.

Comment: havent tried this yet but Bango Analytics definitely works for Mobile Webapps.

Comment: In the above snippet, one should be careful not to declare a global variable 'url' - thus, define a 'var url' instead. (Not kidding: http://blog.meloncard.com/post/12175941935/how-one-missing-var-ruined-our-launch)